# Gibt es ein deutsches Wort für Single-Point-Of-Failure?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich habe zwei Online-Wörterbucher und [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Point_of_Failure) durchsucht und kein deutsches Äquivalent gefunden.

Die Bedeutung ist entsprechend Wikipedia:

> Unter einem Single Point of Failure [...] versteht man einen Bestandteil eines technischen Systems, dessen Ausfall den Ausfall des gesamten Systems nach sich zieht.

Einsatzzweck ist ein technischer Vortrag. Der englische Begriff wird zwar sicherlich verstanden werden, aber ich wundere mich gerade, dass es für so ein wichtiges Konzept keine deutsche Entsprechung gibt.

Comment: Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die Zuhörer denselben technischen Hintergrund wie Du haben, ist wohl hoch. Sie werden kein Problem mit dem englischen Terminus technicus haben, aber potenziell durch jede deutsche Alternative aus dem Konzept gebracht werden. Fachbegriffe werden verwendet, weil ihre Bedeutung klar definiert ist.

Comment: @Roland   Aber es kann doch sein, dass es einen etablierten deutschen Fachbegriff gibt? Ingenieurwesen war schon im 19. Jahrhundert in Deutschland verbreitet...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Warum sollten die Zuhörer diesen besser kennen als der Vortragende? Erfahrungsgemäß ist Denglisch in der Industrie stark verbreitet, wenn nicht sowieso Englisch gesprochen wird.

Comment: "ich wundere mich gerade, dass es für so ein wichtiges Konzept keine deutsche Entsprechung gibt." - Englische Begriffe werden seit Jahrzehnten kaum noch übersetzt, schon gar nicht Fachbegriffe. Ich würde mich nicht wundern, wenn SPOF einfach einer der zahllosen englischen Fachbegriffe im Deutschen wäre. Laut Wikipedia heißt es auch im Spanischen und Italienischen "single point of failure", das Deutsche ist da also kein Einzelfall. Also einfach unübersetzt lassen.

Answer (score 9):

Wie wäre es einfach mit der guten alten **Achillesferse**? Der Ton mag für einen technischen Vortrag vielleicht nicht der beste sein, aber die Bedeutung als *einzige Schwachstelle, die das System außer Gefecht setzen kann*, ist hier auf jeden Fall enthalten. Wenn die mythologische Symbolik nicht so gut ankommt, wäre auch noch das Synonym **der wunde Punkt** denkbar.

Comment: meiner meinung nach der einzige ausdruck, der failure impliziert. alle anderen begriffe sind nicht so nah dran

Comment: Allerdings bedeutet "Single Point of Failure" eben nicht, dass es keine anderen Schwachstellen im System gibt, sondern nur, dass das Eintreten eines einzelnen Fehlers an dieser Stelle zu einem Totalversagen führen kann

Answer (score 7):

Ich würde von

> funktionskritischen Bauteilen

oder

> funktionskritischen Modulen

sprechen.

Dies impliziert, dass bei Ausfall des Bauteils der ganze Apparat nicht mehr das tut, was er soll.

Man könnte vielleicht auch nur von

> kritischen Bauteilen

sprechen, aber vielleicht eher, wenn der Kontext insgesamt schon geklärt ist. Wenn man den Gedanken neu einführt, wäre *funktionskritisch* eindeutiger (und ohne weitere Erklärungen) zu verstehen.

Übrigens spricht man bei Schiffen, Raumschiffen und so weiter wohl gerne auch von

> lebenswichtigen Systemen

Fällt das System aus, geht das Raumschiff in den Orkus, auch wenn andere Teile und Geräte durchaus noch funktionieren.

Answer (score 5):

Mir fallen ein:

- **der Schwachpunkt**
- der neuralgische Punkt
- das schwächste Glied
- die Sollbruchstelle

Unter Umständen passt auch:

- der Stolperstein
- der Hinkefuß
- der Haken
- die Crux

Comment: Nichts davon trifft es aber so richtig, meiner Meinung nach. *neuralgischer Punkt* noch am meisten.

Comment: Doch, **der Schwachpunkt** trifft es genau. Es ist die Stelle, deren Versagen das ganze Dings unbrauchbar macht.

Comment: Schwachpunkt ist etwas wo man viel Schaden anrichten kann. Aber SPOF drückt für mich stärker aus, dass wenn dieses eine Element defekt ist, das gesamte System defekt ist. Es ist eher ein "ganz oder gar nicht", bei Schwachpunkt ist es eher wie ein nicht genügend stark geschützer Bereich, der "verwundbar" ist.

Comment: Wie wäre es dann mit einem Adjektiv um das ganze zu verdeutlichen, z.B. **kritischer Schwachpunkt**?

Comment: *Engpass*? Das ist die Komponente, deren Kapazität die maximale Kapazität des ganzen Systems begrenzt. Und bei Ausfall (Kapazität 0) ist dann auch die Gesamtkapazität 0.

Comment: _Kritischer Punkt_ drückt das eigentlich wörtlich aus. Kann aber sein, dass das nicht so genau verstanden wird. Deswegen finde ich __kritischer Schwachpunnk__ am besten

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach "Schwachpunkt" ist an sich auch nicht passend: Ein SPoF kann "gebaut sein wie ein Panzer" (also alles andere  als "schwach"), aber trotzdem einer sein. Für diese Eigenschaft ist nicht "Schwäche" oder "Instabilität" wichtig, sondern mangelnde Redundanz.

Comment: @tofro Ja, verstehe, gutes Argument. Aber kann man nicht gerade die mangelnde Redundanz als Schwäche ansehen?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Natürlich. Deswegen habe ich ja auch "schwächstes Glied der Kette" als Antwort genommen. Ich finde, dort ist die "Nichtredundanz" klar ein Teil des Bildes. Ein "Schwachpunkt" allerdings erweckt (zumindestens bei mir) den Eindruck, dass dort ein bestimmtes Teil (redundant oder nicht) zu mickrig ausgelegt ist.

Comment: @tofro Ja, ich denke, das ist ein gutes Argument.

Comment: Ich find *Sollbruchstelle* hier fehl am Platze. Die bezeichnet eher einen eingeplanten Bruch, z.B. bei Rettungsflößen. Hier ist eine Reißeine mit dem Schiff verbunden. Das Fass, Fass das Floß enthält schwimmt auf, die Leine wird gezogen, so dass das Aufblasen des Floßes ausgelöst wird und damit das Floß nicht mit dem Schiff untergeht, hat die Leine eine Sollbruchstelle. Die hat mit einem SPoF nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 5):

Nein, es  gibt keine direkte deutsche Übersetzung dieses gut etablierten Fachbegriffs aus dem [Risikomanagement](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Risikomanagement).

Wenn man also eine wissenschaftliche Fehleranalyse betreibt, empfiehlt es sich, diesen Begriff unübersetzt zu lassen. Nur so ist gewährleistet, dass die Zuhörer oder Leser wissen, was gemeint ist. Eine irgendwie geartete Übersetzung müßte zusätzlich definiert werden.

Für eine je nach Auditorium vielleicht doch noch nötige Erklärung des *Single Point of Failure* eignet sich vielleicht die Definitions des [Bundesamtes für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/BSI/Hochverfuegbarkeit/BandAH/AH6_Glossar.html)

> Systemkomponenten oder Systempfade werden als Single Point of Failure (SPoF) bezeichnet, wenn durch ihren Ausfall das Gesamtsystem nicht mehr betriebsbereit ist. Das trifft immer dann zu, wenn eine Komponente eine zentrale Funktion im Gesamtsystem übernimmt und beim Ausfall die Funktionen der anderen Komponenten beeinträchtigt.

Answer (score 2):

**Knackpunkt** wird im technischen Kontext gerne verwendet, auch wenn Duden und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Knackpunkt) es als korrekterweise als umgangssprachlich klassifizieren. Es bringt den technischen Aspekt m. E. etwas besser zum Ausdruck als *neuralgischer Punkt* und *Achillesferse*, die eher biologisch oder medizinisch anmuten.

Den Aspekt, dass damit das Gesamtsystem unbrauchbar wird, sehe ich, wie Dein Kommentar zu Jankas Antwort nahe legt, durch keine vorgeschlagene Alternative addressiert.

[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/single%20point%20of%20failure) landet mit *einzelne Schwachstelle* und *einzige Problemstelle* auch keinen Volltreffer, weckt aber immerhin den Verdacht, dass der englische Begriff auch etwas dehnbarer ist.

Comment: "Beim Tomitshubenzwagen 350 ist der Knackpunkt der Motor" kann ziemlich viel heißen, z.B. dass das Auto einen besonders tollen, zuverlässigen oder sparsamen (aber auch mistigen) Motor hat. "Knackpunkt" kann also u.U. genau das Gegenteil von "Single Point of Failure" bedeuten.

Answer (score 2):

Für "single point of failure" kennt das Deutsche meiner Meinung nach nur einen einzigen, bildlich gemeinten Ausdruck:

> das schwächste Glied der Kette

Durch das Bild der Kette wird verdeutlicht, dass, wenn dieses eine Ding kaputt geht, das ganze System nicht mehr funktioniert. Natürlich muss man normalerweise den Originalsatz bei der Übersetzung mit diesem Ausdruck ein bisschen umbauen.

Comment: sehe ich anders. das schwächste glied ist einfach nur ein schwaches glied. es impliziert weder ein versagen/ nicht-funktionieren noch den damit zusammenhängenden totalausfall

Comment: @Alex Was macht eine Kette, wenn ihr schwächstes Glied reisst? "Tut" sie dann noch?

Comment: dann hat man zur Not 2 kleinere Ketten ;) Ein Bestandteil kann darüberhinaus alles andere als "schwach" sein, und trotzdem vital für die gesamte Funktionsweise sein.

Comment: @alex Und die "2 kleineren Ketten" funktionieren dann noch? z.B. bei einer Hals- oder Panzerkette?

Comment: das ist jetzt nur beim beispiel der kette so - wo übrigens jedes glied das schwächste glied ist. allein dass deine frage interpretationen zulässt, ist ein indikator dafür, dass "das schwächste glied der kette" keine ausreichende alternative ist. viel eher würde das kritischste oder wichtigste glied der kette passen :) und die methapher der kette auf eine tatsächliche kette anzuwenden, ist zu einfach gemacht ;) es geht um eine anwendung/ eine technik, bei dem ein part vital ist. das schwächste glied der kette impliziert das nicht - finde ich

Comment: @Alex Das must du mir erklären - Inwiefern *das schwächste Glied* einer Kette nicht für die Funktion der Kette "vital ist". *Single Point of Failure* hat i.Ü. überhaupt nix mit "kritisch" oder "wichtig" zu tun - Sondern heißt nur "wenn das nicht tut, dann gar nix tut". Ein zentraler Router im Internet kann "wichtig" und "kritisch" sein, aber ist i.A. trotzdem kein SPoF (hoffentlich), weil das Netz auch drumrum kann. Dein Router zuhause ist vollkommen unwichtig, aber (für die Funktion deines Internet-Zugangs) wahrscheinlich ein SPoF.

Comment: naja, einen motor im auto als schwächstes glied der kette zu bezeichnen, finde ich unpassend. der ausdruck impliziert einfach nicht, dass beim ausfall nichts mehr funktioniert (in diesem fall das fahren). schwach ist kein adäquates synonym für vital. dsgdk wird oft in gruppendynamiken verwendet. wenn hier der schwächste nicht mehr funktioniert, bedeutet das nicht direkt einen totalen ausfall der gesamten gruppe. genau so im technischen bereich. und dein beispiel mit meinem router verstehe ich nicht. natürlich ist mein router wichtig, weil ohne ihn mein internetzugang nicht funktioniert?

Comment: Ich fand die Metapher im ersten Moment gut, aber im Endeffekt stimme ich überein, dass sie nicht hält. Genaugenommen ist jedes Glied der Kette - nicht nur das schwächste - ein SPoF. Auf der anderen Seite, stellen wir uns eine Kette mit mehr als zwei Enden vor, die in einem zentralen Glied zusammenlaufen, dann wäre dieses definitiv ein SPoF, nicht aber zwingend das schwächste Glied.

Answer (score 1):

**Einzelschwachstelle**

Nicht unbedingt sehr verbreitet, aber man findet Textstellen, in denen das Wort im Sinn von „Single point of failure“ verwendet wird:

> Deshalb kann ein einzelner Computer die Blockchain nicht ändern, und es gibt keine Einzelschwachstellen ... https://www.invesco.ch/de-ch/risk-reward-01-2018/was-sie-schon-immer-ueber-kryptowaehrungen-wissen-wollten

Answer (score 0):

Ich finde die anderen bis dato genannten Begriffe haben zu wenig des *failure*-Charakters:

> [...] versteht man einen Bestandteil eines technischen Systems, dessen Ausfall den Ausfall des gesamten Systems nach sich zieht.

Ein Schwachpunkt beispielsweise impliziert nicht, dass beim Ausfall die komplette Anwendung streikt. Es ist ein Schwachpunkt - okay - aber das ist noch zu dehnbar bzw. hat ein offenes Ende. Ebenso der neuralgische Punkt. Davon stoppt die Anwendung oder Funktionsweise nicht. Eine Sollbruchstelle ist etwas komplett anderes.

> Der Motor ist die Achillesferse beim Tomitshubenzwagen 350.
>   Die Funktionsweise des Tomitshubenzwagen 350 steht und fällt mit dem Motor.
>   Der Motor ist vital für den Tomitshubenzwagen 350.

*Kritisch* funktioniert in den meisten Fällen ebenfalls sehr gut.

Answer (score -3):

Ich werfe noch

**Das Schräubchen, dass das Schiff zusammenhält**

in den Ring.